# How to allow automatically when a site requests to use my camera?

Tags: adobe, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash

How to allow automatically when a site requests to use my camera. I don't want the settings manager popup dialog of flash player to appear . I want the "allow" permission to be granted always. Is there a way to do it via scripts?.

Comment: Is there a question? Also please cut your text block into smaller paragraph. It's quite hard to read

Comment: What is this "slider" that you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to allow automatically camera for the site,

You can do this per site.

Open the Flash Player Settings Manager,

https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html.

Open the website privacy settings.

Find the site in question and then click the Always allow.

Restart the browser.